# Remove just one word before pattern match in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

Input:

```c
 int foo(int a, void * b, int c);
```

Output:

```c
 int foo(int, void *, int);
```

Want to use "," as pattern to match. If "," pattern is matched then remove the previous word i.e. `a`, `b` & `c`.

Comment: `int c` doesn't have a `,`.

Answer (score 6):

You could use *lookahead* (sometimes called a *zero-length assertion*) if the regex engine you are using supports it e.g. using perl, to match and remove any non-zero sequences of word-characters if and only if followed by `,`

```
perl -pe 's/\w+(?=,)//g'
```

If you want to include other characters in the assertion - such as the terminating right parenthesis `)` after `int c` you can add that as part of a `[...]` character list

```
perl -pe 's/\w+(?=[,)])//g'
```

If you also want to remove any leading whitespace, try

```
perl -pe 's/\s*\w+(?=[,)])//g'
```

Putting it all together we get

```
$ echo 'int foo(int a, void * b, int c);' | perl -pe 's/\s*\w+(?=[,)])//g'
int foo(int, void *, int);
```

Like newer versions of sed, perl can be made to operate on files 'in-place' by adding a `-i` command-line switch.

Answer (score 2):

This should help:
`sed -e 's/[^ ]\+\([,)]\)/\1/g'`
and if you want to remove this ugly spaces:
`sed -e 's/ [^ ]\+\([,)]\)/\1/g'`